# Javascript setInterval timer not stopping with clearInterval

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, timer, expo

I am seeing multiple timers after mounting and unmounting this component. This project is in React Native using Expo.

I start a timer in componentDidMount using setInterval and try to clearInterval in componentWillUnmount. When this timer is created it logs the timer id. When the component unmounts it logs the same timer id, but for some reason the timer continues to run. When the component mounts again there seem to be two timers running.

```
constructor() {
  this.timer = 0;
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.timer = setInterval(() => {
    console.log("here");
    let timeLeft = this.calculateTimeLeft();
    this.setState({ timeLeft });
    if (timeLeft === 0) {
      clearInterval(this.timer);
    }
  }, 1000);
  console.log(this.timer);
} 

componentWillUnmount() {
  console.log(this.timer);
  clearInterval(this.timer);
}
```

Comment: why to use `this.timer=0`? you can declare it locally using let. console `timeLeft` to check what it is printing. Is it returning 0?

Comment: I have already tried using timer as a local variable using let and had the same result. Yes, timeLeft gets to 0, but I am focusing on the clearInterval in componentWillUnmount. There, it logs the timer as the same id as is logged in componentDidMount.

Comment: `let count = 0;  
let timer = setInterval(() => {
    console.log("here");
    count += 1;
    if (count === 10) {
      clearInterval(timer);
    }
    
  }, 1000);

` I validated with count variable and it is giving desired result. How are you validating if timer is not cleared in componentWillMount?